# Convert multi-lines to single-line

Tags: php

I want to turn a line from several lines into one line:

```
$text = 'One line
Two line';
```

I tried through the replacement, but it did not work:

```
$text = str_replace('
', '; ', $text );
```

I want the string to turn into:

```
$text = 'One line; Two line';
```

Comment: replace `\n` with `;` however https://3v4l.org/9kW5Y

Comment: after saving the symbol disappears "\"

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ?????

Comment: http://www.writephponline.com/ : I write "\n" and run, the text turns into "n"

Comment: That site doesn't handle \ apparently, don't use it.

Comment: Your existing code works in my link, also new code https://3v4l.org/t4VIC

Answer (score 0):

Whether CR, LF or both are used as end-of-line depends on the respective editor. "\R" in regular expressions fits all.

```
$text = 'One line
Two line';

$textInOneLine = preg_replace('~\R~','; ',$text);

echo '<pre>'.$textInOneLine.'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
One line; Two line
```